# How to sum responses with specific data in different columns in R

Tags: r, sum

I need to total "how many responses contain X from column 1, y from column 2, and z from column 3".
Column one is boolean, two is numerical (>=100), three is categorical.
How do I write this code in R?

So far, I have this:

```
sample_data <-
 sample_220 %>%
 dplyr::sum(sample.column1==TRUE & sample.column2>=1000 & sample.column3=="Sample Institution")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `dplyr::sum` function. `sum` function is in base R.

To get the count of rows which match the condition you can use the following.

```
result <- with(sample_220, sum(sample.column1 & sample.column2>=1000 & sample.column3=="Sample Institution"))
```

Since `sample.column1` is already boolean we can avoid `sample.column1 == TRUE`.